# green dao update column on play store update has taken place

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao, greendao-generator

this is my Generator class

```
public class Generator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Schema schema = new Schema(1, "app.abc.db.dao");
        createAbcDB(schema);

    }
    private static void createAbcDB(Schema schema) throws IOException, Exception {
        Entity abc = schema.addEntity("Abc");
        abc.addIdProperty();
        abc.addShortProperty("name");
    }
}
```

This is the code where i get abc dao from dao session. This works fine.

```
DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper devOpenHelper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(SurveyActivity.this, "abc.db", null);
        SQLiteDatabase db = devOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
        DaoSession daoSession = daoMaster.newSession(IdentityScopeType.None);
        abcDao = daoSession.getAbcDao();
```

I added one more column

```
abc.addShortProperty("email");
```

to createAbcDB in generator to new version of app. Once users get updated they are getting sql exception saying no column found. Because i am calling on new login

```
dropAllTables(db, true);
onCreate(db);
```

But problem is i have given one time login that user will always come to landing screen on upgrade from play store. So i don't know whether the user is upgraded app or not in order to drop and create all tables.

So my question is how to know my table has altered?

Answer (score 0):

Each time that you do a significant modification like this, you have to update de Schema version number:

```
Schema schema = new Schema(2, "app.abc.db.dao");
```

This way, in the OpenHelper present in the DaoMaster, or in the SQLiteOpenHelper taht you're using, you can control this changes in `onUpgrade()` function:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.i("greenDAO", "Upgrading schema from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + " by dropping all tables");
    dropAllTables(db, true);
    onCreate(db);
}
```